# Programmatically adding button-type columns to grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have grid component which wraps `kendo-grid`. I need to programmatically add columns to it. I've figured out bound columns but I couldn't figure out button columns. The `ColumnComponent` has a template field but it's `TemplateRef` type. How can I accomplish this? The button column will be used for navigation.

Comment: as in app navigation or pages of the grid?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon: app navigation